# How to show presentations on a standalone billboard using Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, keynote

I have a standalone billboard (not connect to any network) onto which I want to show some Keynote presentations from an AppleTV (2k model). How can I set up everything and store everything within the AppleTV so it can show the presentation in an endless loop?

PS: I *do* have network connectivity while setting up the AppleTV of course.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I do not want to involve a network"? You will need connectivity of some kind to get the content onto the AppleTV, can you please clarify?

Comment: @nohillside Content will be loaded ahead of time. At runtime, when I put this slideshow to work as a billboard, no network will be available.

Comment: I made a rather heavy handed edit based on your comment. Feel free to add again whatever I removed, or even roll back completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLC Player. The UI/UX is awful, but it gets the job done.
The Apple TV and your Mac (with the Keynote file) have to be in the same local network when setting up the Apple TV (Apple TV works w/o network after setup).

1. Export the Keynote file as a movie (File > Export To > Movie…)
2. Install VLC player to the Apple TV
   https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id650377962#?platform=appleTV
3. Switch to the "Remote Playback" menu tab in VLC
4. Activate the "Enable Remote Playback" button

This enables an HTTP connection to the Apple TV via the network address(es) shown in the VLC Remote Play screen on the Apple TV (e.g. your Apple TV IP address or Bonjour address).

You can then open the shown IP or Bonjour address (http://…) in Safari on your Mac and upload the exported presentation movie to the Apple TV via the web interface (drag-and-drop or the "+" icon).

After uploading, the (presentation) movie file appears in the bottom area of the VLC Remote Playback screen and can be selected to play.

[image: Apple TV VLC Remote Playback]

Use the playback options (swipe down on Apple TV remote) to enable playback looping.

Answer (score 0):

I found a app called 'Presentation Viewer for TV' in Apple TV app store to view the presentations and it worked.
You can switch slides from apple tv remote and go back and forth.
Here is the link if anyone wants https://apps.apple.com/app/id6446301851